# CodeIgniter Form Action Url Variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

What would be the exact CodeIGniter format to the below form tag. Thanks

```
    <form action="links/link1.php?view=one" method="post">
```

Will this work

```
        echo form_open('links/link1.php?view=one');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right.

```
echo form_open('links/link1.php?view=one');
```

will create a form similar to this:

```
<form action="links/link1.php?view=one" method="post">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: also give a +1 for question if you like